# Why can't I put my image with text next with each other?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am trying to create my own portfolio website. Everything was fine since I tried to put the ib image with the text that says Ib student. I tried to use bootstrap box model first, that doesn't work. Then I tried using float, but that also didn't work. Text always shows at the top of the page and if I try to change its position with `position: absolute` when I resize the page its position gets to somewhere I don't want. To sum up, how can I put these together

How it looks like:
[image: 1]

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF5FD;
}

header {
  background-color: #FF96AD;
}

header h1 {
  color: #FFF5FD;
  font-family: 'Dancing Script', cursive;
  font-size: 6rem;
  padding-top: 16px;
}

header img {
  width: 16%;
  border-radius: 60%;
  margin-top: 30px;
  min-width: 200px;
}

.navbar-brand {
  padding-top: 6px;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}

.capton {
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  margin-top: 18px;
  font-family: 'Spartan', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.ib {
  width: 6%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">



<header id="home">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#home">Batı Gözen</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">My Work</a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">CV</a>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300.jpg/" alt="My Picture">
  <h1>Batı Gözen</h1>
  <p class="capton">"Web Developer, Video Editor"</p>
  <div class="row row-cols-lg-2 row-cols-md-2 row-cols-sm-1 row-cols-1">
    <div class="col">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400.jpg/" alt="IB" class="ib">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <h3> IB Student, 12.th Grade</h3>
    </div>


  </div>


</header>

<section id="resume">
  <h3>My Resume</h3>
</section>



<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF5FD;
}

header {
  background-color: #FF96AD;
}

header h1 {
  color: #FFF5FD;
  font-family: 'Dancing Script', cursive;
  font-size: 6rem;
  padding-top: 16px;
}

header img {
  width: 16%;
  border-radius: 60%;
  margin-top: 30px;
  min-width: 200px;
}

.navbar-brand {
  padding-top: 6px;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}

.capton {
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  margin-top: 18px;
  font-family: 'Spartan', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.ib {
  width: 6%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">



<header id="home">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#home">Batı Gözen</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">My Work</a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">CV</a>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300.jpg/" alt="My Picture">
  <h1>Batı Gözen</h1>
  <p class="capton">"Web Developer, Video Editor"</p>
  <!--<div class="row row-cols-lg-2 row-cols-md-2 row-cols-sm-1 row-cols-1">
    <div class="col">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400.jpg/" alt="IB" class="ib">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <h3> IB Student, 12.th Grade</h3>
    </div>
  </div>-->
 
<div class="row">
<div class="col d-flex">
    <img class="ms-auto" src="https://via.placeholder.com/400.jpg/" alt="IB" class="ib">
</div>
<div class="col d-flex">
    <h3 class="my-auto me-auto"> IB Student, 12.th Grade</h3>
</div>
</div>

</header>

<section id="resume">
  <h3>My Resume</h3>
</section>



<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

**Maybe you want this type of result.**
To get this result I have commented out your code snippet and insert mine check that out. Also you can customize left and right using the `ms-auto` and `me-auto` to adjust the margin in the left nad right.

Comment: Everything is fine and that is what I need but there is only one thing that I couldn't understand. I tried changing images margin with editing ms-auto in css but that didn't work. How can I adjust images place, margin?

Comment: First you have to apply the flex display. I have shared the solution why arent you checking from there?